# How to back up messages when sink is down?

Tags: architecture, high-availability, failover, fallback

We're brainstorming what would be a good behavior in the following scenario:

- we have ~30 servers which publishes ~300 messages/sec to a sink
- the sink goes down occasionally, but we don't know when and how long
- the servers are in auto scaling group, and they can be taken down at any
  time (i.e. we cannot hold/store unpublished messages in the server
  local)

What is the recommended behavior of publishers when the sink is down in this scenario?

More particular question would be:

1. What is the recommended secondary storage to failover? - file system, database, queue
2. what should be the failover behavior
3. what is a good strategy to recover the messages after the sink is back and up

Comment: Can you have more than one sink? Also what is the transport between the source and the sink? And why does the sink fail?

Answer (score 0):

First approach: I'd suggest something that's not exactly the answer you are looking for.
I've had very similar scenario. But servers sending messages to sink (in my case NServiceBus) were allowed to retain messages in case they failed sending messages to sink (because sink was down). My servers were also part of auto scaling scheme. But I was using AWS and that allowed termination lifecycle hooks (which basically allows postponing termination if certain conditions weren't met) , so I used them to try postponing termination until all messages were sent successfully (server had an API that facilitated this via AWS lambda function). If it timed out then we'd take a snapshot of server and later restore messages.

Second approach: This is more around making your message queue (i.e. the sink) highly available. Now, I'd think that message delivery from server to sink could fail for many reasons (may be server driver error or server had some internal bug etc. or wire to the sink was broken!) So the system sending messages must be capable of storing messages. For message based distributed system it is absolutely essential to having fail safe message sender and highly available receiver. So if you had to work on making your sink highly available; you could work on making your sink highly available by having it behind load balancer and having multiple servers or unconventional way of choosing secondary sink at the time of sending message (which is prone to server internal issues). Not exactly your answer but this Kafka architecture document would give your food for thoughts https://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-kafka

Comment: In the 1st approach, how do you retain failed messages? Store in disk?

Comment: @gyoho Yep. In our case it was MSMQ. We had to back up whole MSMQ system drive (to avoid writing custom code for exporting to some other place).